# Updates without UAC

Tags: windows-10, updates, uac, gaming, steam

I have a set of public gaming PCs to take care of. Current issue is when it comes down to play any game. The game usually needs to be updated so windows prompts for admin password (UAC) in order to update it and play. I'd like to avoid this. I have several strategies in mind but i'd like some advice in which is the best way to proceed.

Note: Lowering UAC settings is out of question (currently set to max).

Note2: A game can be launched from different platforms such as Steam, Origin, Epic games, etc.

- Add UAC exception for a set of programs.
- Default launch of a program as administrator without UAC.
- Use task scheduler to update any necessary games on PC boot.
- Read in a forum that if the installation process is done using admin privileges, the game won't ask for admin password when needing to update. Can anyone confirm this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Don't ask multiple distinct questions in a single post. Please ask the registry question in another post. As for your UAC question, it suffers from the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271445). Instead of asking for advice on your proposed solutions, focus on stating your requirements and asking how to achieve them.

Comment: I think the question is fine now. The problem is described clearly. OP has proposed some approaches, but it feels like they're open to other solutions as long as they meet requirements.

Comment: There is a way to do this with a scheduled task, but it is not documented as far as I have been able to find or rather it is documented but has changed since then. CCleaner uses it to run scheduled cleaning scripts, but when I tried to duplicate their method it simply didn't work. Best guess: MS has changed how it works, not documented the change (possibly understandable), but the dev has hacked it somehow (or knows something I don't).

Comment: If you could work it out, you could just schedule the updates for startup. The machines may take a minute to boot if there were lots of updates, but they'd be ready when someone launched the game. Sorry, didn't post as an answer because I never got it to work myself.

Comment: @AVLien I did play with the startup scheduler, but being public PCs, means usually the user is not valid. As an example, a user might use his steam account, and found no way to input the default steam credentials (with the games that I desire to update)